# Change string of pairs of data to JSON for python to return to Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

Working on Zap to load data into a Google sheet.  Have the basics done, just want to dig down into the one field.

In a Zap I'm working on I have an 'orderdetail' field that has in things like (there are :

BundledItems: None
Cost: 97.19
CurrencyISO: USD
DateShipped: None
GiftMessage:
GiftWrapPrice: 0.0
GiftWrapTax: 0.0
HSCode: None

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import re

values = re.sub('\\n', '","',input_data['orderdetail'])
values = re.sub(':', '":"', values)
values = '"' + values + '"'

return {values}
```

I'd like to return these 'pairs' to be used in later steps of the Zap, but can't quite get it converted to JSON for returning.